# $2\int_{0}^{1} \cos(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = \frac{2m(\cos(m\pi)+1)}{\pi (m^2-1)}$ when $m \ge 2 $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$2\int_{0}^{1} \cos(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = \frac{2m(\cos(m\pi)+1)}{\pi (m^2-1)},\; m\ge2$$

I can't seem to be able to prove this.

I have tried using the identity $\sin(a)\cos(b) = 1/2 (\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b))$ to get  $$\int_{0}^{1} \cos(\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \sin((m-1)\pi x) + \sin((m+1)\pi x) dx$$ and then solving but am unable to reproduce the solution.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: linearize $\cos a\sin b$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: ive tried using the identity sin(a)cos(b)=1/2(sin(a−b)+sin(a+b)) but have had no success

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar that's exactly the right idea.  So where are you getting stuck?

Comment: im confused as to how it simplifies to the form on the RHS

Answer (score 6):

Your method gives $\int_0^1 (\sin (m + 1)\pi x+\sin (m -1)\pi x)dx=\frac{-1}{\pi}\bigg(\frac{\cos (m+1)\pi -1}{m+1}+\frac{\cos (m-1)\pi -1}{m-1}\bigg)$. As the cosines are both $-\cos m\pi$, this simplifies to $\frac{2m (\cos m\pi +1)}{\pi (m^2-1)}$. As a sanity check, let's take $m=2$, so my claim is that the answer is $\frac{8}{3\pi}$. Indeed $$2\int_0^1\cos \pi x\sin 2\pi x dx=2\int_0^1 2\sin \pi x\cos^2 \pi x dx,$$which by $u=\cos\pi x$ gives $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{4}{\pi}u^2 du=\frac{8}{3\pi}.$$

Comment: apologies i forgot to write the 2 when typing the equation out my confusion comes from where you say that the cosines are both $-cos(m\pi)$? how does that simplify

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar From the identity $\cos (y+\pi)=-\cos y$.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!